# How to communicate with SUP (Sybase Unwired Platform) MBO using kendo UI mobile?

Tags: kendo-mobile, sup, hybrid-mobile-app

Developing a hybrid application using Kendo UI mobile framework. My requirement is to communicate with SUP (Sybase Unwired Platform) MBO's. As i'm newbie, need someone's help who have implemented the hybrid application before using SUP. Please suggest me how to communicate and what are the process required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUP allows you to develop mobile application which are native and HWC, native applications are developed by using the object api generated from SUP, HWC on the other hand is The Hybrid Web Container is the runtime on the device within which Mobile Workflows (HTML UI) are executed.\

Mobile Workflow Forms editor is a Hybrid App Designer tool which allows you to create HTML screens in a graphical interface.
The Mobile Workflow Forms editor uses the Hybrid Web Container as the runtime for Mobile Workflow packages. The Mobile Workflow Forms Editor included with Sybase Unwired Platform is a tool that helps you design the user interface and test the flow of the business process for a mobile workflow application.

In SUP 2.2 provided capability to develop Hybrid Apps using third-party tools such as Sencha and Cordova (formerly PhoneGap). SUP 2.2 allows you to generate Hybrid api and you can use any html framework to create SUP apps which will run inside the HWC container in the mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you @Rakshi, and few more question. 1) Can i communicate with SUP without using HWC. My requirement is, I want to develop hybrid application using any third party UI framework (mostly kendo UI) and using SUP as middleware without using HWC.  2) Or there any other option to access native APIs from SUP via js instead of MBO's in PhoneGap.

Comment: No you dont have much other options provided by SAP, and SAP dosent recommends and SAP will not be supporting any other custom design or architecture, So if u r developing a SUP based hybrid app it has to run inside the HWC container

Answer (score 0):

For your question regarding the third party framework (like Kendo UI). If the framework does support oData, then you can take the approach of using the oData Native API that SUP or SMP provides.